# How to calculate daily one year or 52 week high/low for stock on a rolling basis

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyquant

I want to be able to calculate and include into my data frame 52 week (or one year) high and low for a given stock.

#### Data to calculate 52 week.one year high/low

```
library(tidyquant)
bhp <- tq_get("bhp")
```

#### Function that I built to calculate high/low

```
one_yea_high_low <- function(df, start, end){
  require(tidyverse)

  df1 <- df %>% filter(date <= end & date >= start)

  one_yr_high <- df1 %>% select(high) %>% as.vector %>% max() %>% as.data.frame()
  one_yr_low  <- df1 %>% select(low) %>% as.vector %>% min() %>% as.data.frame()

  df3 <- bind_cols(one_yr_high, one_yr_low) 
  colnames(df3) <- c("yr_high", "yr_low")

  return(df3)
}
```

It works for one search at a time:

```
start_date <- min(bhp$date) 
end_date   <- start_date + years(1)
one_yea_high_low(bhp, start_date, end_date)
  yr_high yr_low
1   87.43  36.37
```

#### But I'm unable to vectorise it over the entire dataframe

this does not work (bummer!)

```
map(bhp$date, ~one_yea_high_low(df = bhp, start = (.x - years(1)), end = .x))
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Any ideas on how to go about this and include the final result back into the main df.

I really want to use dates to calculate the rolling window as the data I have has got gaps, i.e. days when not traded etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at tibbletime, pretty easy with that. I took highs and lows from adjusted now. Here you can join this to old one by creting key columns from year for example.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tibbletime)
bhp <- tq_get("bhp")

bhp_tbltime <- tbl_time(bhp, index=date)

bhp_tbltime %>%
  time_summarise(
    period   = "yearly",
    high = max(adjusted),
    low  = min(adjusted)
  )
```

and rolling would be something in these lines:

```
    roll_max <- rollify(max, window = 252)
    roll_min <- rollify(min, window = 252)

    bhp_tbltime %>% 
      mutate(max252 = roll_max(adjusted),
             min252 = roll_min(adjusted)) %>% 
      tail()

# A time tibble: 6 x 9
# Index: date
        date  open  high   low close  volume adjusted max252   min252
*     <date> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2017-11-13 42.37 42.86 42.31 42.70 2134300    42.70  44.15 33.01988
2 2017-11-14 42.15 42.18 41.42 41.69 2795400    41.69  44.15 33.01988
3 2017-11-15 40.99 41.31 40.72 41.21 2540100    41.21  44.15 33.01988
4 2017-11-16 41.44 41.44 41.02 41.38 3029400    41.38  44.15 33.01988
5 2017-11-17 41.30 41.41 41.14 41.38 2183900    41.38  44.15 33.01988
6 2017-11-20 41.00 41.13 40.79 41.12 2211300    41.12  44.15 33.01988
```

Comment: Hakki that would not work as the high/low is based on calendar year. I'm looking to solve this with a rolling window. Am I being clear with my request....do let me know and I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: would that work? 252 is pretty common in financial data for year. Min would be just creating roll_min and applying. I propaply just read question too fast and thought it was year high-low. Both are there now.

Comment: Thanks, this is still a partial fix only. My data has stocks that have not traded for a month and son, so it becomes a bit difficult to use the 252 period. Is there a way to use dates?

Comment: not that I know of. I would fill those days that are not trading with last value, and then use this.

Comment: Just to keep this up to date, with `tibbletime 0.1.0` you now should do this instead of `time_summarise()`:                                                            

    `library(tidyquant);
    library(tibbletime);

    bhp <- tq_get("bhp");

    bhp_tbltime <- tbl_time(bhp, index=date);

    bhp_tbltime %>%
      mutate(date = collapse_index(date, "yearly")) %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise(high = max(adjusted), 
                low = min(adjusted))`